# Python base class method call: unexpected behavior

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

Why does `str(A())` seemingly call `A.__repr__()` and not `dict.__str__()` in the example below?

```
class A(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'repr(A)'
    def __str__(self):
        return dict.__str__(self)

class B(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return dict.__str__(self)

print 'call: repr(A)  expect: repr(A)  get:', repr(A())   # works
print 'call: str(A)   expect: {}       get:', str(A())    # does not work
print 'call: str(B)   expect: {}       get:', str(B())    # works
```

Output:

```
call: repr(A)  expect: repr(A)  get: repr(A)
call: str(A)   expect: {}       get: repr(A)
call: str(B)   expect: {}       get: {}
```

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3140/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str(A())` does call `__str__`, in turn calling `dict.__str__()`.

It is `dict.__str__()` that returns the value repr(A).

Answer (score 3):

I have modified the code to clear things out:

```
class A(dict):
   def __repr__(self):
      print "repr of A called",
      return 'repr(A)'
   def __str__(self):
      print "str of A called",
      return dict.__str__(self)

class B(dict):
   def __str__(self):
      print "str of B called",
      return dict.__str__(self)
```

And the output is:

```
>>> print 'call: repr(A)  expect: repr(A)  get:', repr(A())
call: repr(A)  expect: repr(A)  get: repr of A called repr(A)
>>> print 'call: str(A)   expect: {}       get:', str(A())
call: str(A)   expect: {}       get: str of A called repr of A called repr(A)
>>> print 'call: str(B)   expect: {}       get:', str(B())
call: str(B)   expect: {}       get: str of B called {}
```

Meaning that str function calls the repr function automatically. And since it was redefined with class A, it returns the 'unexpected' value.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted a workaround solution to it. Check it out ... you might find it useful:
http://blog.teltub.com/2009/10/workaround-solution-to-python-strrepr.html

P.S. Read the original post where I introduced the issue as well ... There problem is the unexpected behavior that catches you by surprise ...